# how to exit iframe

Tags: php, html

**1.html**

```
<form id="abc" method="post" action="navigate.php">
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="a1" /> A 1
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="a2" /> A 2
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="b1" /> B 1
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="b2" /> B 2
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="c1" /> C 1
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="c2" /> C 2
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

**navigate.php**

```
<?
if ($_POST['nav']==a2) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=page_1.php\">";} ?>
```

**2.html**

```
<iframe src="1.html"/>
```

When i select a2 and press go it goes to page_1.php but inside the frame. I want the main window to go to page_1.php. Is there any solution for this??

Comment: Please be sure to turn on PHP error messages and warning during development.  The PHP code you have posted contains at least one important warning.

Comment: Is this select inside your iframe?

Comment: yes they are all in iframe. but i want to see page_1.php in the default window. not in the frame...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the target attribute of the form tag to determine the frame/window the submit should be targetting to. In you case use target="_top" to open the result in the top frame (the main window)

```
<form id="abc" method="post" target="_top" action="navigate.php">
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="a1" /> A 1
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="a2" /> A 2
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="b1" /> B 1
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="b2" /> B 2
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="c1" /> C 1
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="c2" /> C 2
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

The problem is that it will open in the top frame (the window) in all cases, so independent of what you choose as a value for the radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your doctype, you can include a `target` attribute on `form` elements just as you can with `a` elements.  Something like this:

```
<form id="abc" method="post" action="navigate.php" target="_parent">
```

This would display the resulting response in the frame just above the iframe, which is probably the window.  Or to ensure the whole window:

```
<form id="abc" method="post" action="navigate.php" target="_top">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [target="_top"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp):

```
<form id="abc" method="post" action="navigate." target="_top">
```

Answer (score 0):

try using some javascript like:

```
<script>

( window.parent || window ).location = "LOCATION_HERE.PHP";

</script>
```